# How to set different tax rate for each products in virtuemart

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I am usng vm2 in my joomla project.I want to set the tax rate of product1 to 4.71% and product2 to 1.25% .  How we can set different tax rate for each product through admin side.

thanks in advance

Comment: How is it related to `php` if you're asking how to change it through the admin side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to set up a per product tax rule for each level of tax you want to put on a product. Then in the individual product in the product pricing you can select which tax to apply to the price from a drop down list.